# Measure desired control size immediately after changing DataContext

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a custom control which I want to render on a canvas. Before I render it, I must first calculate its size. I have this code which I want to get the size of the control before it is rendered:

```
var customView = (Control)Activator.CreateInstance(viewModel.CustomViewType);
customView.DataContext = viewModel;
// Bindings not updated yet... I want to update them here
customView.Measure(new Size(double.MaxValue, double.MaxValue));

// Use customView.DesiredSize
```

However, measuring the control right after assigning the `DataContext` does not update the bindings in time to get the proper size of elements. How can I ensure the bindings are updated immediately after setting `DataContext` so that I can make a proper measurement?

I have tried adding right after setting the `DataContext`:

```
 customView.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { }), DispatcherPriority.DataBind);
```

This line causes a `System.InvalidOperationException` in `WindowsBase.dll`, with no info on what went wrong.

**Update**: The other similar question suggested was [Updating Binding immediately when DataContext changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662892/updating-binding-immediately-when-datacontext-changes). I don't think this answer suites my case. Because I'm working with custom views (which can come from anywhere), I would like to avoid having to force each view to conform to that implementation of `MeasureOverride`, if at all possible. Also, invoking a dispatcher action right before measurement gives me the error described above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating Binding immediately when DataContext changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662892/updating-binding-immediately-when-datacontext-changes)